# How can I give user access to folder owned by root without adding user to sudoers file?

Tags: linux, unix, file-permissions, folder-permissions

I have a directory owned by root (/var/log/apache2). I would like a user to have read only access to this folder - without changing the group owner of this folder. Is it possible to do that without adding user to the sudoers file?

Comment: You'll get a better answer on https://serverfault.com/.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your system is set up.

If you're lucky, the `adm` group already has read access to those files. If so, then simply add your user to the `adm` group:

```
sudo usermod -aG adm SOMEUSER
```

The `adm` group is commonly used to provide read access to system log files, without having to give the user super powers. Your user will also be able to read anything else `adm` group has access to.

If those files have no group access at all, (ie they show `-rw-------` and are owned by root/root), then the next best option is to use `setfacl` to give your user read access to those files:

```
sudo setfacl --modify u:SOMEUSER:rx /var/log/apache2    # let them in to the dir
sudo setfacl --modify u:SOMEUSER:r /var/log/apache2/*    # let them read the files
```

Be aware that once logrotate shuffles those files, your user may not have access to the new log file. You might have to set up your `setfacl` commands in a cron job to keep access going.

It is also possible to expand permissions on that folder, but persisting that change involves modifying the /etc/logrotate.d/apache2 file. Since your package manager likely created /etc/logrotate.d/apache2 (and will probably want to modify it at some point) I don't recommend going that route.